# How to allow only decimal numbers in a TextBox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on asp.net web application.

I have a textbox in that textbox I need to allow decimal number before pressing the submit button. so how to do this at client side before submitting the submit button.

if it could be done by javascript, ajax aur from the code behind please let me know.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/425670/Textbox-only-for-Numeric-decimal-values

Comment: i would say..validate it on sumbit..using regex or whatever method you like...checking decimals before submit seems a bad idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a code-behind alternative, you can rely on `TryParse`. Sample code for `Button1` and `TextBox1`:

```
string currentDot1 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
string currentDot2 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
string currentDot3 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator;
decimal curVal = 0m;
if (TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && (TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot1) || TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot2) || TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot3)) && decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out curVal))
{
    //curVal is valid decimal
}
else
{
    //NO DECIMAL
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this fail if the number is without 0 (which still can be a decimal?)

Comment: @Noctis it will also fail with 5 (or with any other integer). I understood that the OP wants a decimal, meaning a number including a dot; not a .NET decimal type. This code is expected to consider wrong anything not including "."

Comment: well, he's not too clear, and by the way, have a look at my comment for the other answer (user3024816)

Comment: @Noctis I guess that now you cannot complain about the level of detail of my answer :)

Comment: nope, but your conditions are all messed up, and you have an extra `)` in there ...

Comment: @Noctis Please, don't edit my code without my permission (unless having an error). Where is the extra )?

Comment: @Noctis well... as I was saying: actually, the "." should also be accounted in the most likely scenarios as far as users might input it even though the given country has a different decimal separator, because it is of general use. But this eventuality would go against my proposal (as far as the TryParse wouldn't work either)... something noting worthy anyway. So... something else you want to add?

Comment: Edited for readability, no code changed. Why did you change it back to the scroll_scroll_scroll ?? look at : `TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot3))Code Alignment` it's the extra `)`. 
Que tengas un buen fin the semana :)

Comment: @Noctis `TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot3))` is right: the first closing bracket is for the `Contains` statement and the second one for the the bracket started in `(TextBox1.Text.Contains(currentDot1)` which includes all the `OR` statements (letting `AND`s are `OR`s free is rarely a good idea :)). Regarding readability, this is an opinion-based statement; I prefer it in this way (well... it is just in the limit, one member more to the condition and I would rely on a boolean flag).

Comment: must have missed that `(`. It's good then, even though i wouldn't leave it in a line ... scrolling isn't your friend i'm afraid :).

Comment: @noctis Regarding your last bit, I don't quite understand your sentence, is this french? LOL Gracias, tío; pero no hay paz para los currantes (los pobres). Que vamos... fin de semana ninguno (igual que el resto de días) :)

Comment: @Noctis As said, I don't like too big condition statements, neither vertically nor horizontally (prefer to rely on building up flags outside the statement); but, in case of choosing, I choose horizontally; as said: opinion-based decision. You shouldn't think that what you like is more valid than what others like :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two way, either through built in validation of asp.net or using javascript. Through javascript you can do it as follows (This will prevent user from entering character key, hence only numbers will be allowed):

```
<asp:Text onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" runat="server"/>

<script>
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what happens if the user region is using a different value than '.' for the decimal part? (some countries do, i know, i know ...crazy ... but then, some countries speak english as well ...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing your own custom validation code in javascript or server-side validation, there are libraries out there that allow you to do the validation client side with jquery.

Add these script references (you would need jquery as well):

```
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#idOfMyForm").validate(
            {
                rules: {
                    IdOfMyTextBox: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
                if(!$("#idOfMyForm").valid(){
                    e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting
                    alert("My form is not valid.");
                }
                //continue submitting the form, do whatever you need to do.
            });
        });
</script>
```